# TypeError: global.__reanimatedWorkletInit is not a function. (In 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit(_f)', 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit' is undefined)

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

```bash
TypeError: global.__reanimatedWorkletInit is not a function. (In 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit(_f)', 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit' is undefined)
```

I am using React Native (not Expo), and I don't even have reanimated downloaded. I had it downloaded, then I removed it and rebuilt the app, and it's giving me this error now.

Things I've tried:

- Deleting `node_modules` and re-running `yarn install`
- `git reset HEAD~` to a previous commit where I didn't install the reanimated packages

Comment: have u followed the installation process?

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

Comment: when I installed it, yes i followed all those steps. but now I've removed it. and even rollbacked to a previous commit before i installed. and i'm still having this error without "reanimated" anywhere in my codebase

Answer (score 12):

I just followed the below steps to solve this issue.

**step1:** `npx react-native run-android`
**step2:** `npm start -- --reset-cache`

and it solved

Comment: This was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what I ended up doing to solve this was:

- Deleted the whole repository from my local
- Cloned it again from Github
- Uninstalled the app from my android emulator

Then it seemed to work, so maybe it was an error related to cache or something lingering around even after I had removed all instances of the word/package "reanimated" from my whole codebase.

Comment: it healped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using **Expo** in a bareworkflow

- Clear app memory
- run `expo start --dev-client --clear`

Comment: This also works for the Expo managed workflow when running `yarn expo start --clear`

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the solutions from Stack Overflow and they're not working.

Here is my fix: first check your version of `react-native-reanimated` and then see the actual documentation of the right version for your configuration. I am using version 2.4.1 and have solved by this [link](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.3.x/fundamentals/installation)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone's scratching head in 2023, I solved it by using **useLegacyImplementation**

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" useLegacyImplementation>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Comment: I'm still scratching my head because adding `useLegacyImplementation` throws an error for me. I'm using reanimated `^3.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue doing this:
https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-redash/issues/395

On top you just have to do this: `import 'react-native-reanimated';`
on your app or index file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a require cycle warning from a git submodule inside the src folder which I thought wasn't doing any harm but turns out fixing that solved this issue. I am unsure why the require cycle was causing so much grief but I guess if you've got a require cycle in your output try solving that and it may fix this.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was degrading react-native-reanimated to **^2.6.0**. It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and simply moved the babel plugin `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to the last place in the babel's config as stated in [the doc](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/#babel-plugin).

I should probably mention it worked for me before but when I started migrating the react-native app for web this was the problem for me. I am using expo. I had to run expo with `--clear` CLI arg as `expo start --dev-client --clear`.

Answer (score -1):

I Just solved this issue by doing these steps:

1. close Metro bundler
2. run this command

> npm start -- --reset-cache

> react-native start --reset-cache

3. rebuild the project again